# How do you say “deleter” in French?

Tags: suffixes

**Scenario**

**Worried mother:** Please be careful son. Always wear your mask and hood. If the great deleter sees your face, then you’ll cease to exist.

**Son:** I promise. Stop worrying.

This passage stood out to me due to the word **deleter**. I have checked that *deleter* isn’t found in Oxford dictionaries etc. However, even though it is not present in those reputable dictionaries and that this word seems to have been coined, we can all deduce that a **deleter** is somebody or something which deletes another person/object.

I’m trying to find the French equivalent. Would it be “supprimerateur/actrice” ?

Comment: The correct spelling is *delete(r)*, but even addressing that issue, you're right that it doesn't really show up. It's a plausible word based on the productiveness of -r but not an established one. I would say the same is true in French. Hence, I would expect *supprimateur/trice* to be totally understandable, even if it strikes one as a neologism.

Comment: This "great deleter" evokes *la grande faucheuse* (The Grim Reaper) for me.

Comment: @jlliagre It surely does in terms of referent, but not meaning, to borrow the semanticists' terms :) It has a significant level of tongue-in-cheek from the technology realm. Also, that which is reaped is collected and brought somewhere, but that which is deleted is gone forever.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Lol I can’t believe I spelt the word incorrectly!  Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: @None Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: @jlliagre Thank you for this. :)

Comment: deleter is not really a word in English. It's some made up thing. *Writers make up what they damn well please all the time*. If the "great deleter" is a killer, you can use suppresseur, based on the fact that suppression means to kill someone.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Maybe *le grand faucheur* (play of word with *la grande faucheuse*) or better *le grand gommeur*. An eraser is *une gomme* and *gommeur* isn't listed in main dictionaries.

Comment: Why not *supprimeur* ?

Comment: @XouDo Si j'ai bien compris, on attend un mot qui "n'existe pas" (dans le dico).

Comment: @jlliagre Oui justement supprimeur n'a pas l'air exister pour les dictionnaires (sauf pour cnrtl dans le moyen français)

Comment: @XouDo C'est vrai, et *supprimeur* est nettement plus élégant que l'horrible *supprimateur* ;-)

Comment: The Great Deleter is one of the final bosses of the game, and lies on the border of The Slimeverse. https://slime-rancher-fanon.fandom.com/wiki/The_Great_Deleter Slime rancher.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The answer is le supprimateur.

Comment: It was a quizz?

Comment: @XouDo Lol no  It was the answer I got from the comments to my question.

Comment: Please edit to include your sources.  If this came from another user, you should note it in the answer.

Answer (score -1):

« Le grand nettoyeur », qui est un mot d’argot pour « tireur à gage ».
Dans votre contexte, si “the great deleter” exprime la mort, la métaphore adaptée serait « la grande faucheuse ».

Comment: Les commentaires figurant sous la question expliquent pourquoi ceci ne répond pas à la question et par ailleurs celui qui a posé la question a déjà trouvé sa réponse !